# Can an AWS EC2 AMI be replaced with the same ID?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

Is it possible to replace a custom AMI with a new one while retaining the original AMI Image ID? Reason I asked this is I have various Cloudformation templates that spin up auto-scaling EC2 groups. Instead of having to go through the process of updating my Cloudformation template with the new AMI Image ID and reloading I would simply like to terminate the running instances which would make new instances start up. This "terminate instances" approach would work if I could replace an AMI and keep the same Image ID. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to re-use an AMI ID.

You could put your AMI ID in a [nested stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html). That way you only need to change the AMI ID in one location.

More sophisticated CloudFormation users take advantage of [Custom Resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/crpg-walkthrough.html) that call-out to another service to determine which AMI to use, but that's somewhat complex ([example](https://github.com/sebsto/AMIFinder)).